# Creating dynamic hyperlinks in jquery script

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

Is there a way that i can force my dynamically generated "read more" text to appear as a link (so that it shows the finger-pointing cursor when a user hovers over it) ? The overall code works correctly to expand the paragraph when clicked but all i am trying to do is get the (read more) to act as a link (looking at it you wont think its clickable).

I expected that adding -a- tags in line 11, to wrap the text within the code should work, but no luck with that:

```
$(this).text( $(this).text() == 'Read Less' ? "<a href='#'>Read More</a>" : "<a href='#'>Read Less</a>");
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eewule/m3n9sxws/)

Comment: Your first `.text()` is better with `.html()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in CSS by targeting your `morelink_L3` and doing something like the following:

```
.morelink_L3 {
 cursor:pointer;
 margin-left:1.4em
}
```

I'm also seeing in your JSFiddle that you have multiple elements with the same ID. Since you have the `morelink_L3` class you might as well get rid of the `moreLink` ID.

Comment: Thanks all, @mplungjan, the 2nd line of you css has done the trick for my cursor. I have also used -color:#0079c8;         text-decoration: underline;- to give it an appearance of a link.

Comment: Hmm, that was not my answer. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50137335/295783) was a lot more elaborate than this. I just edited it so I could change my vote

Comment: Using CSS to style the span will not let a visually impaired user understand it is something with an action attached

Answer (score 0):

1. No href on the link makes it not look like a link - either add an href (and a preventDefault) or use CSS to style as link. Added value of having a link is the tabability and allowing visually impaired users to know this has an action
2. You used .text to insert html.

This works better - note the hover and the preventDefault

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.morelink_L3').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).siblings().hasClass("readmore")) {
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("readmore");
    } else {
      $(this).siblings().addClass("readmore");
    }
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Read less' ? 'Read more' : 'Read less');

  });
});
```

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.story_L3 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 13px
}

.readmore {
  height: auto !important;
}

#moreLink {
  margin-left: 1.4em
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="outer">this is main box
  <div class="story_L3">This is inner box <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, habitant sapien la oreet mi taciti in nunc s emper, netus neque pulvinar aliquet diam con vallis. Facilisi lacus felis integer solli citudin luctus laoreet leo natoque,
    placerat sodales non porttitor accumsan arcu aliquet, sagittis risus poten ti hi men aeos dui inceptos aliquam. Sociosqu euismod in augue quisque at qui s tempor facilisi ad, cubilia vivamus accumsan suspendisse venenatis sagittis class volutpatelementum,
    vestibulum lacus habitasse libero felis luctus consequat mattis.</div>
  <!--<div id="moreLink"></div>-->
  <a href="#" class="morelink_L3">Read more</a>
</div>

<div class="outer">this is main box
  <div class="story_L3">This is inner box <br /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, habitant sapien la oreet mi taciti in nunc s emper, netus neque pulvinar aliquet diam con vallis. Facilisi lacus felis integer solli citudin luctus laoreet leo natoque,
    placerat sodales non porttitor accumsan arcu aliquet, sagittis risus poten ti hi men aeos dui inceptos aliquam. Sociosqu euismod in augue quisque at qui s tempor facilisi ad , cubilia vivamus accumsan suspendisse venenatis sagittis class volutpatelementum,
    vestibulum lacus habitasse libero felis luctus consequat mattis.</div>
  <a href="#" class="morelink_L3">Read more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, true: its better for accessibility, to use code than css, so i am reverting back off the css i added. @AjAX, you said : "Your first .text() is better with .html()" that hasnt worked

Comment: The reason we missed the complete issue, was the lack of HREF - you inserted an anchor inside a span

Comment: Ok, simplyfying the output section, i have replaced the code with this             $(".morelink_L3").click(function() {
 $(this).html($(this).html() == 'Read Less' ? "Read More" : "Read Less");
});

Comment: You can just replace the complete script with mine

Comment: Yes, i've just tried doing that. But upon testing it didnt create the hyperlink (although it expands). I will investigate further and update

Comment: See my html too!